# Heterogeneous JSON array not parsing with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json structure I am trying to parse with jackson which at the top level consists of a heterogenous array:

```
[
  {
    "machineuuid": "e74f75b9-d819-4377-b5cd-8bc0bd02dee2",
    "version": 5,
    "flags": 10
  },
  [
    {
      "ma": [
        {
          "arr": [
            3,
            7,
            0
          ],
          "ts": "2014-12-02T18:56:50.514Z",
          "u": "74e4d525-ae1a-5406-8b4b-0166d03bf2a4"
        }
      ],
      "u": "46e800d6-2e8c-469c-9d39-9f985bf19728",
      "web": [
        {
          "arr": [
            3,
            1,
            0
          ],
          "cc": [
            "7a26ff80-6a42-4648-bdbc-0076e7e31088"
          ],
          "p": 100,
          "t": "Disney.com | The official home for all things Disney",
          "ts": "2014-12-02T18:56:55.173Z",
          "u": "http://disney.com/"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

The top level java looks like:

```
public class ActivityUpload {

    @JsonProperty(index = 0)
    MachineInfo machineInfo;

    @JsonProperty(index = 1)
    List<UserUpload> userUploads;

}
```

The inner portions of the parsing work fine with unit tests (e.g. MachineInfo, UserUpload),
it is just the top level where the outer array contains a MachineInfo json object in array[0], and the array of UserUpload json objects is in array[1].

The exception that is thrown is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.myapp.domain.ActivityUpload out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: [
  {
    "machineuuid": "e74f75b9-d819-4377-b5cd-8bc0bd02dee2",
    "version": 5,
    "flags": 10
  },
  [
    {
      "ma": [
        {
          "arr": [
            3,
            7,
            0
          ],
          "ts": "2014-12-02T18:56:50.514Z",
          "u": "74e4d525-ae1a-5406-8b4b-0166d03bf2a4"

.... lines omitted 

]; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:749)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:745)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1203)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:147)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:126)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2146)
    at com.myapp.domain.ActivityUploadTest.testPayload1(ActivityUploadTest.java:95)
```

I am guessing the problem might be my use of the JsonProperty(index=0) annotation, which I see was added in 2.4.0 (I am currently using 2.4.4). I read the docs as the index parameter being able to select a particular position in an array. I would prefer to have a simply annotated class/es that I can give to jackson to parse rather than having to hand craft the parsing of the json directly with lower level methods (e.g. objectMapper.readTree()).

I have no control over the format of the json that is sent to me to change in any way.

I have looked at many other posts, but they seem to deal with homogenous arrays, with all the same type of data within that array. I deal with that in many places and those work as expected. I am hoping this is a simple oversight on my part.

Comment: The index parameter of the JsonProperty annotation is not meant to map array elements to Java fields. Javadoc says: "This index is typically used by binary formats, but may also be useful for schema languages and other tools." I'd read JSON as tree and find the object nodes that correspond to your Java model.

Comment: In a sense, this is similar to a binary format in which the specific position within an array is as important as the value. I was hoping to avoid a manual process. I will probably have to do a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there is a way to handle this by specifying "serialize-as-array"

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ machineInfo, userUploads })
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class ActivityUpload {
  @JsonProperty
  MachineInfo machineInfo;

  @JsonProperty
  List<UserUpload> userUploads;

}
```

and it should then match what you have.